# How can i get a list of radio checkboxes based on previously checked checkboxes in form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with getting a limited list of radio checkboxes in form based on checked checkboxes on previous page of this form. there is a relation M2M categories <--> organization. So checking several categories, I wpuld liek to get a list of all organizations to which these categfories belongs to. List of radio checkboxes was loadad with ajax. I know that I should filter somehow by the value of checked checkboxes but don't know how to do it. The commented code in the below html shows how it should look like. Firstly it was static.

```
here is the part with checkboxes:
<div class="form--steps-container">
        <div class="form--steps-counter">Krok <span>1</span>/5</div>

        <form action="form-confirmation.html" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <!-- STEP 1: class .active is switching steps -->
          <div data-step="1" class="active">
            <h3>Zaznacz co chcesz oddać:</h3>
            {% for category in categories %}
            <div class="form-group form-group--checkbox">
              <label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="categories"
                  class = "checkbox"
                  value={{ category.id }}
                />
                <span class="checkbox"></span>
                <span class="description" id = "opis"
                  >{{ category.name}}</span
                >
              </label>
            </div>
              {% endfor %}

here is the part with radio checkboxes loaded with ajax:

<!-- STEP 4 -->
          <div data-step="3" id = 'steps'>
            <h3>Wybierz organizacje, której chcesz pomóc:</h3>
            <!--
            <div class="form-group form-group--checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="organization" value="old" />
                <span class="checkbox radio"></span>
                <span class="description" id = "span">
                  <div class="title" id ="name">Fundacja “Bez domu”</div>
                  <div class="subtitle" id = "description">
                    Cel i misja: Pomoc dla osób nie posiadających miejsca
                    zamieszkania
                  </div>
                </span>
              </label>enter code here
            </div>

            <div class="form-group form-group--checkbox" id = "changelist-form">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="organization" value="old" />
                <span class="checkbox radio"></span>
                <span class="description">
                  <div class="title">Fundacja “Dla dzieci"</div>
                  <div class="subtitle">
                    Cel i misja: Pomoc osobom znajdującym się w trudnej sytuacji
                    życiowej.
                  </div>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
            -->

            <div class="form-group form-group--buttons" id = "guzik">
              <button type="button" class="btn prev-step">Wstecz</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn next-step">Dalej</button>
            </div>
          </div>

app.js - here with ajax I have loaded a list of all organizations, which should be filtered by value of checked checkboxes. However I tried several times and can't get the expected result

$(document).ready(function()
 {
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/institution/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
      for (let i =0; i<data.length; i++)
      {
        console.log(data[i].categories)
        //var check = data[i].categories
        //for (let i=0; i<check.length; i++){
            //console.log(check[i])
        //}
        //if(check[i] == )
        //console.log("stop")
        //console.log(data[i].categories)
        //console.log(check[1])
        //console.log(data[i].categories.length)
          var rows = $('<div class="form-group form-group--checkbox">\n' +
          '              <label>\n' +
          '                <input type="radio" name="organization" value="old" />\n' +
          '                <span class="checkbox radio"></span>\n' +
          '                <span class="description" id = "span">\n' +
          '                  <div class="title" id ="name">' + data[i].name + '</div>\n' +
          '                  <div class="subtitle" id = "description">' + data[i].description + '</div>\n' +
          '              </label>\n' +          '                </span>\n' +

          '            </div>');
          $(rows).insertBefore("#guzik");
    }
  }
  });
 });
```

Comment: Can you show your json output ? Also , you just need to checked the checkboxes based on the json values ?